# if statement not evaluating condition as expected

Tags: javascript, json, if-statement, evaluation

I am using a `$.getJSON` function to return JSON from an API of employee salaries. For each entry, I have a counter that goes up for each employee returned. I added a list that allows the user to choose the department the employee works in as a variable to check when the function is wrong. When the check function runs for all employees, it works as expected returning 1000 employees. However, when I add in the if statement, it does add any employees to the employee counter.

I am logging the selected department to the console and can see the department is correctly selected. I think put in a string of `"Department of Police`" to use in the function and it return 186 employees. If I use the variable `checkedValue` which shows in the console the same value I would expect the same function to return 186 employees but it does not. The value is held in the JSON object as a string so I'm not sure if the wrong data would be the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="button-area">
                <button id="check">Check the radio button</button>
                <button id="action">Do Action</button>
            </div>
            <div id="checks">
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul id="list"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Sans', Tahoma, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

#page {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 2px black;
}

#content {
    margin: 10px;
}

#button-area {
    padding-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var url;
var myNewObject;
var myObject;
var departmentArray;
var cleanedDepartmentArray;
var checkedValue;
var budget = 0;
var employees = 0;

function setTheList() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        myObject = data;
        for (var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
            departmentArray.push(myObject[i].department_name);
        };
        $.each(departmentArray, function(i, el) {
            if ($.inArray(el, cleanedDepartmentArray) === -1) {
                cleanedDepartmentArray.push(el);
            }
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < cleanedDepartmentArray.length; i++) {
            $('#list').html("");
            $('#checks').append("<li><input type='radio' name='department' value='" +
                cleanedDepartmentArray[i] + " '>" + cleanedDepartmentArray[i] +
                "</li>");
        };
    });
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Initialized with " + employees + " employees and " + budget +
        " budget.");
    url = 'https://data.montgomerycountymd.gov/resource/54rh-89p8.json';
    myObject;
    myNewObject;
    departmentArray = [];
    cleanedDepartmentArray = [];
    //set the list
    setTheList();
    //get checked radio button value
    function getCheckedValue() {
        checkedValue = "";
        checkedValue = $("input[name=department]:checked").val();
        console.log(checkedValue);
    };
    //call geojson
    function getData(checkedValue) {
        getCheckedValue();
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            myNewObject = data;
            console.log("my new object: ", myNewObject)
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i].department_name === checkedValue) {
                    employees++;
                };
            };
            console.log(checkedValue);
            console.log(employees)
        });
    };
    $('#check').on('click', function() {
        getCheckedValue();
    });
    $('#action').on('click', function() {
        getData(checkedValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: `console.log(data[i].department_name, checkedValue, data[i].department_name === checkedValue)` Are the values what you expect?

Comment: the `checkedValue` argument in `getData` is a different object to the (global) `checkedValue` set in `getCheckedValue`

Comment: In the case that the data behind the adress is valid and not some testing values: delete it, now! I'm not familiar with the exact law there but it might get very serious, up to some jailtime!

Comment: Don't you need to initialize `cleanedDepartmentArray` to an empty array? You could step through your code in the debugger, examining variables as you go, to track down this sort of problem.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi this is publicly available data on an open data website. Governments generally publish all employees salaries.

Comment: @toraburo I don't need to clean the array, that's so the list doesn't generate duplicates. It isn't necessary for the next function.

Comment: @epascarello yes, I believe so.

Comment: @Jaromanda X I see the value with a space at the end, however when I use a string value without a space at the end, the function works.

Comment: @adin no idea what you're taking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a space after the value of the value attribute in the line below. I assume this shouldn't be here?

```
$('#checks').append("<li><input type='radio' name='department' value='" +
                cleanedDepartmentArray[i] + " '>" + cleanedDepartmentArray[i] +
                "</li>");
```

Seeing if I can highlight this any clearer for you:

There's a space after the value of the value attribute in the line below. I assume this shouldn't be here?

```
$('#checks').append("<li><input type='radio' name='department' value='" +
                cleanedDepartmentArray[i] + " '>" + cleanedDepartmentArray[i] +
                "</li>");
```

Just to see if I can highlight it any better:

```
cleanedDepartmentArray[i] + " ' <<< this bit
```

Comment: Yup, this was it. Thank you!